# Why is my neural network always giving me the same predictions?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I'm trying to create a sequential neural network where the output is 12 non-exclusive probabilities ( probability of A, probability of B, probability of C, ... ). My network seems to learn the most common output and always predict that for every input. All of my output values are always "1" or "0", nothing inbetween, and always the same value in the same position (details below).

I'm nowhere near being a ML expert, so it's possible that the solution is very simple.

I've tried using different batch sizes (varying from 8 to 128) and many different loss functions, but none seem to help.

How I created the model with Keras:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add( Dense( 150, input_dim=9600, activation='relu') )
model.add( LeakyReLU(alpha=.01) )
model.add( Dense( 50, activation='relu') )
model.add( LeakyReLU(alpha=.01) )
model.add( Dense( 12, activation='sigmoid') )

metrics_to_output=[ 'accuracy' ]
# I've tried many loss functions, not just mean_squared_error
model.compile( loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=metrics_to_output )
```

This might not be relevant, but this is how I prepare the data and train the model. I have also tried using `train_on_batch`:

```py
def generate_data_from_files( file1, file2 ):
    input = numpy.load( file1, allow_pickle=True )
    output = numpy.load( file2, allow_pickle=True )

    # The file only has 2 values, and I generate 12 probabilities derived from those 2 values
    transformed_output = output.copy()
    new_shape = ( output.shape[ 0 ], 12 )
    transformed_output.resize( new_shape )

    for x in range( 0, len( output ) ):
        #First 6 probabilities model the value of output[ x ][ 0 ]
        transformed_output[ x ][ 0 ] = 1 if output[ x ][ 0 ] <= -5.0 else 0
        transformed_output[ x ][ 1 ] = 1 if output[ x ][ 0 ] <= -3.0 else 0
        transformed_output[ x ][ 2 ] = 1 if output[ x ][ 0 ] <= -1.0 else 0
        transformed_output[ x ][ 3 ] = 1 if output[ x ][ 0 ] >= 1.0 else 0
        transformed_output[ x ][ 4 ] = 1 if output[ x ][ 0 ] >= 3.0 else 0
        transformed_output[ x ][ 5 ] = 1 if output[ x ][ 0 ] >= 5.0 else 0
        #Second 6 probabilities model the value of output[ x ][ 1 ]
        transformed_output[ x ][ 6 ] = 1 if output[ x ][ 1 ] <= -5.0 else 0
        transformed_output[ x ][ 7 ] = 1 if output[ x ][ 1 ] <= -3.0 else 0
        transformed_output[ x ][ 8 ] = 1 if output[ x ][ 1 ] <= -1.0 else 0
        transformed_output[ x ][ 9 ] = 1 if output[ x ][ 1 ] >= 1.0 else 0
        transformed_output[ x ][ 10] = 1 if output[ x ][ 1 ] >= 3.0 else 0
        transformed_output[ x ][ 11] = 1 if output[ x ][ 1 ] >= 5.0 else 0
    return input, transformed_output


input, output = generate_data_from_file( file1, file2 )
model.fit( x=input, y=output, batch_size=8, epochs=1 )
```

I expect to get 12 values ranging from 0 to 1, each one modeling a probability. However, when I use the network to make predictions (even on the training data) I always get the same identical output:

```
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

This is a reasonable average guess because the 2nd and 3rd booleans are usually true and everything else is usually false, but I never see any variation from this prediction, even on training data where the expected output is something else. I do occasionally see a 0.9999999 or a 0.000001 in place of a 0 or 1, but even that is rare.

My takeaway is that I'm setting up the model to always predict the average case. Any feedback or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**Edit:
Thanks for your advice, everyone. After reading more about this, I think what's happening is that my output layer is becoming saturated. I'm switching to using softsign in place of sigmoid (and adjusting the logic to expect -1 to be the floor instead of 0) and hopefully that will help.**

Comment: I think you better provide the code you use to print this. But from my experience, it's either you predict from the training data or the pre-processing is wrong.

Answer (score -3):

You're using sigmoid activation function for your output layer.

```
model.add( Dense( 12, activation='sigmoid') )
```

Sigmoid outputs either 0 or 1. I think what you're looking for is the softmax activation function which outputs values between 0 and 1, and all of the (12) values add up to 1. You would then do argmax to find the highest value and take that as your prediction.

Two other things: Why are you using two activation functions in your hidden layers? Use one or the other, not both.

```
model.add( Dense( 50, activation='relu') )
model.add( LeakyReLU(alpha=.01) )
```

Mean squared error is used for regression problems, based on your description this seems to be a classification problem.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, especially about the double layering. However, I do not want all of my probabilities to add up to 1 (that's what I tried to mean by "non-exclusive probabilities" but I understand how that's ambiguous). Can sigmoid not output, for example, 0.5? If not, is there something like softmax that doesn't enforce a sum of 1?

Comment: This `Sigmoid outputs either 0 or 1` is somehow wrong, Keras's Sigmoid is actually float value between 0 to 1. And for @Mack question, it's yes, Sigmoid can output 0.5 in case of the input is 0.